# module reads package javax.annotation from both jsr305 and java.annotation

Tags: java, annotations, openapi-generator, java-module

I go the error message:

```
module reads package javax.annotation from both jsr305 and java.annotation
```

In my build.gradle I used these dependencies:`

```
implementation "javax.annotation:jsr305:1.0"                  //  for @javax.annotation.Nonnull & Nullable
implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2"  //  for @javax.annotation.Generated`
```

In my OpenAPI generated source these annotations are used:

```
@javax.annotation.Nonnull & Nullable`
@javax.annotation.Generated`
```

I tried to use an exclude but it didn't work:

```
implementation ('javax.annotation:jsr305:1.0') {  
  exclude group:"javax.annotation", module: "javax.annotation-api" 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Move from javax.annotation to jakarta.annotation in source code:

```
@jakarta.annotation.Generated
@jakarta.annotation.Nonnull
@jakarta.annotation.Nullable
```

and in my build.gradle include this dependency:

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'one.gfw:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1'
}
```

And in my module-info.java I included:

```
requires jakarta.annotation;
```

n.b. The other dependency I found `jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5` didn't have all the annotations I wanted, only @javax.annotation.Generated and not Nonnull & Nullable, and so I used `one.gfw:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1`

---

As an aside, my source code was generated by the OpenAPI generator and I included the option `useJakartaEe: 'true'` in the generator's config to generate "jakarta.annotation" in place of "javax.annotation". In my OpenAPI generator's project - separate from the above project - here's my config in its build.gradle:

```
openApiGenerate {
 generatorName  = "java"
 inputSpec      = "${rootDir}/specs/${project.specName}"
 outputDir      = "${buildDir}/${project.apiName}"
 apiPackage     = "${project.packageName}.controllers"
 modelPackage   = "${project.packageName}.models"
 configOptions.set([
  dateLibrary: "java8",
  useJakartaEe: 'true'
])
}
```

Hope this helps.